# SASL PLAIN mechanism handshake failed

Tags: python, apache-kafka, confluent-kafka-python

resolve this error
SASL PLAIN mechanism handshake failed

i am able to create topic produce and consume messages through terminal

```
from confluent_kafka import Producer


def delivery_report(err, msg):
    if err is not None:
        print('Message delivery failed: {}'.format(err))
    else:
        print('Message delivered to {} [{}]'.format(msg.topic(), msg.partition()))


conf = {
    'bootstrap.servers': 'localhost:9092',
    'security.protocol': 'SASL_PLAINTEXT',
    'sasl.mechanisms': 'PLAIN',
    'sasl.username': 'admin',
    'sasl.password': 'admin-secret'
}

producer = Producer(conf)

topic = 'test'
message = 'Hello, Kafka!'
producer.produce(topic, key=None, value=message, callback=delivery_report)

producer.flush()
```

Comment: Please [edit] and show us your Kafka broker properties and setup where you have defined admin user and password, and exactly what terminal commands you've been using